# Beautiful Soup (Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to access the list of restaurants in between the p tags.

```html
<p class="openclosemonth" id="May2014">May, 2014</p>

<p>
<strong>CLOSED:</strong><br />
-- Haveli, Cambridge (Inman Square), MA<br />
-- Ma Soba, Boston (Beacon Hill), MA<br />
-- Milestone, Wellesley, MA<br />
-- Scosso, Peabody, MA<br />
-- Sonny Noto's, East Boston, MA<br />
-- Viva Mexican Grill, Wayland, MA<br />
</p>

<p>
<strong>OPEN:</strong><br />
-- The Abbey, Cambridge, MA<br />
-- The Bancroft, Burlington, MA<br />
-- Beantown Pho and Grill, Boston (Back Bay), MA<br />
-- The Briar Rose, Hyde Park, MA<br />
-- Caffe Nero, Boston, MA<br />
-- Cheeburger Cheeburger, Swampscott, MA<br />
</p>
```

Any suggestions about how to pull out the desired data?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest using BeautifulSoup ;-) Have you had any specific difficulties so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all text from a `<p>` tag, strip whitespace, skip what is empty, then skip the first:

```
for para in soup.find_all('p'):
    if para.strong is not None:
        print para.strong.get_text()
        lines = filter(None, (t.strip() for t in para.find_all(text=True)))[1:]
        print '\n'.join(lines)
        print
```

I included a test for a `<strong>` child tag to select just those specific paragraphs.

For your input, that gives:

```
>>> for para in soup.find_all('p'):
...     if para.strong is not None:
...         print para.strong.get_text()
...         lines = filter(None, (t.strip() for t in para.find_all(text=True)))[1:]
...         print '\n'.join(lines)
...         print
... 
CLOSED:
-- Haveli, Cambridge (Inman Square), MA
-- Ma Soba, Boston (Beacon Hill), MA
-- Milestone, Wellesley, MA
-- Scosso, Peabody, MA
-- Sonny Noto's, East Boston, MA
-- Viva Mexican Grill, Wayland, MA

OPEN:
-- The Abbey, Cambridge, MA
-- The Bancroft, Burlington, MA
-- Beantown Pho and Grill, Boston (Back Bay), MA
-- The Briar Rose, Hyde Park, MA
-- Caffe Nero, Boston, MA
-- Cheeburger Cheeburger, Swampscott, MA
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my Q. I get that a lot of people want me to spend a long time carefully reading the Beautiful Soup documentation, and I would normally, but due to extreme time constraints I was unable to this time.  Also, this isn't homework or anything -- Just a personal project.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 compatible version using a simple approach.

```
for para in soup.find_all('p'):
    if para.strong is not None:
        for t in para.find_all(text=True):
            print (t.strip())
```